# Aneuploidy in meiosis

Tags: meiosis

I am quite confused about nondisjuction in anaphase II. If the double chromosome is not segregated, isn't it double. On pictures they are drawn as single but I don't understand why, and if they are double do they duplicate themselves in the S phase?

[image]

What is confusing me in picture above is cell (n+1) , why are all chromosomes single? I thought, after end of division in the third cell (labeled as n+1) there should be 3 chromosomes with single chromatid,  and 1 chromosome with 2 chromatid joined at centromeric region, as it is drawn in picture above that show nondisjunction in cell during anaphase ii . When and how do these 2 chromatids get physically separated?

Comment: can you add a little explanation about what is confusing? what pictures are you referring to? could you add them?

Comment: Hmm after your comment on  @ImtiazRaqib's answer it is now clear you are asking about when and how the centromeric region of 2 chromatids (of respective chromosome in respective cell division) get physically separated later-on if it skips the separation during metaphase-anaphase. Excellent question but original question too should contain diagram.

Comment: edit (addition) suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From **[Study.com](http://study.com/academy/lesson/nondisjunction-in-meiosis-definition-examples-quiz.html)** >>

On the off chance that nondisjunction happens amid **anaphase II** of **meiosis II**, it implies that no less than *one set of sister chromatids did not isolate*.

In this situation, two cells will have the **typical haploid number of chromosomes.** Additionally, one cell will have an **additional chromosome (n + 1)** and one will **miss a chromosome (n - 1)** due to the *nondisjunction of the chromosomes*.

Here is a picture reference taken from **[Google.ca](http://dmucklow.weebly.com/uploads/4/4/9/8/44986695/128321280.jpg)** >>

[image: Nondisjuntion of chromosomes]

In the ***image provided in the question***, the chromosomes are not indicated clear and concisely, so it is very hard to follow through the logic of segregation of the daughter cells to **(n + 1)** and **(n - 1)** chromosomes.

As you can see from the updated image reference in the answer, we can notice that the `cell` that underwent **nondisjunction** in *anaphase 2* gives rise to 2 daughter cells, in which, one cell receives the ***non-segregated*** chromosome plus one copy of a *sister chromatid* which makes it **(n + 1)** and the other daughter cell receives one segregated *sister chromatid* **ONLY** which makes it **(n - 1)**.

On an additional note, from **[Biology Exams 4 U](http://www.biologyexams4u.com/2012/09/what-happens-if-non-disjunction-occurs.html#.WFA-uPkrJPY)** >>

> Fusion of n+1 gamete with normal gamete (n) = 2n + 1 or Trisomic.
>
> Fusion of n-1 gamete with normal gamete (n) = 2n - 1 or Monosomic.
>
> In short, Nondisjuntion in meiosis II leads to trisomy (2n+1) or
>   Monosomy (2n-1).

Comment: What is confusing me in picture above  is cell (n+1) , why are all chromosomes single. I thought there should be 3 single chromosomes and 1 double as it is drawn in picture above that show nondisjunction in cell during anaphase ii . I hope i am clear. :)

Comment: Look at the **updated answer** with a more clear and concise image. Hope it helps.